# Net::IMAP uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imap

I really don't know where to start with this one, but I am (first time) using `Net::IMAP` and I am getting the following error:

```
NameError in EmailsController#connect
uninitialized constant Net::IMAP

Extracted source (around line #4):

2  
3 def connect
4  imap = Net::IMAP.new('outlook.office365.com')
5  imap.authenticate('LOGIN', '**@**.com', '**')
6  imap.examine('INBOX')
7  @emails = imap.search(["RECENT"])
```

Not really sure what is going on here, I don't have to have anything in my `Gemfile.rb`? Or anything else before I set the `imap` variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to `require 'net/imap'` at the top of the file to bring `Net::IMAP` into scope.